# Центрирование резинового по высоте блока

Tags: css

Добрый день!

Подскажите пожалуйста, какие есть варианты центрирования резинового по высоте блока.
Ширина блока 100px, высота по содержимому.

Интересуют варианты на чистом CSS, без использования JS.

Comment: начнем с простого.Для каких браузеров?

Answer (score 1):

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

но только если у блока не задан float. Если он всё же задан, то оберни блок в ещё один div и выставь ему ширину и маргин

Comment: Если чо, то это центрирование по горизонтали. margin: top right bottom left;

Comment: @RedMonkey, необходимо сделать центрирование по вертикали, а не по горизонтали. И блок должен быть резиновым по высоте. 

Ps. прочитаете вопрос.

Comment: тогда ставь диву
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
иначе без таблиц никак =)
Ps. по вопросу не понятно что центрирование нужно по вертикали

Comment: @RedMonkey что непонятно в выражении "по высоте блока"?

Comment: какой вопрос, такой ответ. Если блок резиновый по весоте это ещё не значит что его нужно центрировать по вертикали

Answer (score 0):

http://cssing.org.ua/2007/04/26/another-css-valign-method/

http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/pozitsionirovanie/vertikalnoe-vyravnivanie-otnositelno-roditelya.html

Comment: Еще не проверял (нет времени)... Соответствуют ли данный ссылки вопросу, а именно: блок по высоте резиновый?

Comment: @koza4ok, проверил. Не соответствует. Есть еще варианты?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант: запихнуть блок в таблицу height=width=100%:

```
<table width=100% height=100%>
   <tr>
      <td valign='center' style='vertical-align:center;'>
         <div class='container'></div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Нет, интересует вариант без использования таблиц.

Comment: А если таблицами, но не таблицами? :) http://jsfiddle.net/g66wd/

Comment: @Cypher, спасибо. Уже сделал аналогичным способом. Вам +10